# AJAX search NOT dynamic - keep results and doesn't count results

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have got live ajax search and trying to group results into 2 categories which is work. The problem I have got is while I am typing or removing a character the list results is increasing of the same items instead of defining. Also the number of results is showing in a very strange way.

```
$("#searchterm").keyup(function (e) {
var q = $("#searchterm").val();
$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=:isbn=0-13-727827-6',

function (data) {
    $("#results").empty();
    $("#results").append("Results for <b>" + q + "</b>");
    $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
        var title = item.volumeInfo.title;
        $.each(item.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers, function (i2, type) {
            $("<div/>")
            .append(title)
            .appendTo("div[id='" + type.type + "']");
            $(".number").append(" total " + type.type.length);
        });
    });

});
});
```

Please have a look at the fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/sFn8t/** and feel free to amend it so other can use it as an example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to amend the code and get it working. Please follow my updated fiddle - I hope it will be helpful for beginners like me.

```
$("#searchterm").keyup(function (e) {
var q = $("#searchterm").val();
$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=:' + q,

function (data) {
    var tmp = {};

    $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
        var type = item.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].type;
        if (!tmp[type]) {
            tmp[type] = [];
        }
        tmp[type].push(item);


    });
    var html = [];
    $.each(tmp, function (key, item) {
        html.push('<h3>' + key + ' - ');
        html.push(item.length + '</h3><ul>');
        $.each(item, function (i, val) {

            html.push('<li><a href="page/?id=' + val.id + '"><strong>' + val.volumeInfo.title + '</strong></li></a>');

        });

        html.push('</ul>');
    });

    $('#results').html(html.join(''));

});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sFn8t/1/

Comment: The only one problem I still have got so far is - when I delete all characters from search bar some results are still staying. ;-(

Comment: When the characters are deleted it throws an error: *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"*. Looks to me like something is undefined in: `item.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].type`. It probably just needs some null checks.

Comment: Thank you Snixtor. Can you help me with amending the fiddle?